# Rails ActiveRecord sorting with diff values as parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to trigger different sorting queries based on specific key=value parameters in rails. I need help with my syntax. I hope you can see what I am trying to achieve?

in controller:

```
def index
   if params[:sort = originality?].present?
    #perform your logic with sort
   end
   #Other logic
 end

def index
   if params[:sort = dynamics?].present?
    #perform your logic with sort
   end
   #Other logic
end
```

In view:

```
   <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Rankingz <b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <!-- We are passing the sort parameter here -->
    <li><a href="?sort=originality">Originality</a></li>
    <li><a href="?sort=dynamics">Dynamics</a></li>
    <li><a href="?sort=Execution">Execution</a></li>
    <li><a href="?sort=Battle">Battle</a></li>
    <li><a href="?sort=Votes">Votes</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't define the index action again, change you index action to look like:

```
def index
  if params[:sort].present?
    sort_fields = ['originality', 'dynamics', 'execution', 'battle', 'votes']
    @instance_var = ModelName.order(params[:sort]) if sort_field.include?(params[:sort])
  end

    @instance_var ||= ModelName.all #ensure if the instace variable is not nil.
end
```

Comment: Thank you! local variable = array is the answer and then if statement. Thanks for your ruby expertise!